# MVVM binding nested user controls

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have MainViewModel which contains collection of tab view models. Each tab can be different type of view model (different view). When users adds new tab, the corrent type of tab view is recognized (base on view model) but it is not binded at all. For example one view model contains GridView with itemsSource set to collection but if I set breakpoint on the get property of that collection it is never hit. (but when I instantiate this view model I set this collection to new ObservableCollection so NotifyPropertyChanged event is fired) - so I suppose that data context is set wrong for the nested user control (view model)

Comment: This is not a question. Nevertheless, my suggestion is to take a look at the Visual Studio output window. If there are any Binding errors, you will find them there. Also, post some XAML and some code if you expect some answers

Answer (score 0):

Typically in the MVVM model you bind your data using a Data Template that aligns your viewmodel as the datatype and the view as the view you specify.  MVVM usually follows a model of the view as the presentation and the viewmodel as the data and is bound typically with a data template in XAML in typically the app.xaml or a specifically created MainWindowResources.xaml file for relations for types and bindings.

Usually when something is not bound correctly I have often found because the view is presented but the viewmodel is not bound to it the data has no idea how to be shown or updated.

EG: In the commonly used MSDN reference MVVM: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2026

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AllCustomersViewModel}">
<view:AllCustomersView />
</DataTemplate>
```